# Installation: react-native init fails - Apparent network issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, terminal, react-native

I'm trying to install React Native on my Mac. Everything was going fine until I reached the "react-native init" part.

Terminal gives me this message:

> X's-imac-2:~ Y$ react-native init NewProj
>   This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/Y/NewProj
>   Installing react-native package from npm...
>
> npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "react-native"
>   npm ERR! node v5.5.0
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.5.3
>   npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
>   npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
>   npm ERR! syscall connect
>
> npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 23.235.40.162:443
>   npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>   npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
>   npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
>   npm ERR! network 
>   npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>   npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/Y/NewProj/npm-debug.log
>
> npm install --save react-native` failed

My network is fine and I've tested pinging the server and it works. Not behind a proxy either. I've tried init multiple times.

What could be going wrong? Also can someone explain me react-native init works? Like do I just make my project name or am I missing something?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a way to solve it?

Comment: No sadly. Will update this post if I do.

Answer (score 0):

I know this could look stupid. I encountered with similar issue on windows. Once I paused my virus guard it worked fine.

Also can you show the steps you followed here ?It's highly unlikely to be something with installation but these npm acts weird sometimes.